# angular callback to application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I am using angularjs & cordova in my app. I am stuck at one point i have an button which is used to authorize a person or user. It sends me to the link where i want to allow the user to access. It is getting access and the url of the link shows that the user is http://(websitename).com/approve but how can i get back the user  token into my app so that token can be used for further purpose and second thing how can i send my user from the accessing window back to the app.

HTML code:

```
<button ng-click="login()">Login</button>
```

Controller code:

```
$scope.login = function () {

     angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        var url = 'https://(website_name).com/1/authorize';
        var key = 'My App key';
        var callbackURl = 'http://localhost/myApp/';
    loginService.login(url,key,callbackURl);
});
```

factory code:

```
.factory('loginService', function($http,$window){
return {
    login: function(url,key,callbackURl){

var clientURL = url+'?callback_method=postMessage&return_url='+encodeURIComponent(callbackURl)+'&expiration=never&name=myApp&response_type=token&key='+encodeURIComponent(key);

        var clientWindow = window.open(clientURL,"_blank");

        }
   }
})
```

I want to callback my user along with the token to 'http://localhost/myApp/'

how can it be done or is there any easier way to do such queries??

-thanks in advance.

Comment: In this case you are opening a new window which is going to make a post to your callback URL. This assumes that the toke data is being sent to your server. You server needs to pick up this token and then send it to the client side.

Comment: @AbhinavGujjar it can be done with localStorage (store token in storage, then check in application. Or it can be done with socket (more interesting solution).

Comment: Read this http://frederiknakstad.com/2013/01/21/authentication-in-single-page-applications-with-angular-js/